# Clickonce deployment results in "null reference" error in InitializeComponent();

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

Clickonce deployment of a Winforms application results in "null reference" error in InitializeComponent(); Running the executable directly does not produce the error.

Any ideas as to why that might happen?

edit:

Seems to be related to getting the value of Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Using JIT Debugging in Visual Studio the Call Stack is: ProgramName.exe!ProgramName.MainForm.MainForm() + 0xf5 bytes 
ProgramName.exe!ProgramName.Program.Main() + 0x23 bytes

Answer (score 1):

This is not a ClickOnce problem per se, it's a problem with your application. If you track down the exe file under \apps\2.0\obfuscatedfoldername\obfuscatedfoldername\xxxx...tion... (where xxxx is the 1st four characters or your assembly name) and double-click on it, does the application run? Probably not.

Put some try/catch statements in with a messagebox showing the exception if it has one, to try to figure out *exactly* what line of code is causing your problem. It doesn't make sense that it would be Environment.GetFolderPath, unless you're doing something weird with it, so find the exact line causing the problem and post it back here.